# how to fetch particular rows in python

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, for-loop

I have a table in sql server 2008 with some `11-columns and 11-rows`

I have function where I fetch data from the data using **fetchall()** like:

```
def main():
   cursor.execute("select * from [dbo].[mytable] where isActive=1 and IsDownloaded=0")
   result = cursor.fetchall()
   for row in result:
       ConfigId =row[0]
       pattern = row[1]
       ....
```

Here I can fetch all rows with this FOR loop,where as I want to use this same table in two programs to fetch only particular rows

fetching rows *1st-6th and last 11th row* in **one program** and  *remaining 4 rows* in another in **other program**.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can do something like this:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
prog1 = result[0:6]
prog1.extend(result[12])
prog2 = result[6:11]
```

Now prog1 will have rows from 1 to 6 and 11. prog2 will have remaining 4.